# How to find the value of this functional equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find the value of $p(a - 3) - p(a + 3)$ if $p(a) = 4a$.

What I tried:

$$\tag{1}pa = 4a, p = 4$$
$$\tag{2} 4(a - 3) - 4(a + 3) = 4a - 12 - 4a - 12 = -24$$

The answer is correct: $-24$. But it seems to me that I did not solve correctly, because I cannot solve other similar problems. What do you think? Is the solution correct?

Comment: $p(a)$ is a function of $a$. You can't write $p(a)$ as $p\times a$.

Comment: Please see how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/29979#29979).

Comment: Solving one problem correctly doesn't mean that you can solve all the other questions in the same way, even though they are similar ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p$ is a function. $p(a)=4$. $p$ is not a constant. Hence your first line is not right.

$p(a-3)=4(a-3)$ and $p(a+3)=4(a+3)$ and hence the working follows from your second line.

Comment: ok. but how to solve that?

Comment: You have been given the rule of $p$ right? you just have to use the rule to evalue $p(a-3)$ and $p(a+3)$

Comment: yep. I don't understand, if $p(a)=4a$ then what is equal $p(a-3)$ ?

Comment: yes, $p(a-3)=4(a-3)$

Comment: please tell me, are the following statements true?: if $q(y) = y - 2$ then $q(y - 5) = y - 2 - 5 = y -7$ and $q(4y) = 4(y - 2) = 4y - 8$

Comment: $q(\color{blue}{4y}) = \color{blue}{4y}-2 \ne 4y-8.$